# Making a picture with an Array

Tags: java, arrays, image

I am trying to make a picture with an array filled with asterisks. The problem is, I have no clue how to make the asterisks appear in certain coordinates. If you could help that would be great.

```
public class Array {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        horizontalLine();
    }

    public static void horizontalLine () {

        String [][] anArray;
        anArray = new String [2][8];

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i ++) {

            for (int j = 2; j < 8; j ++) {
                System.out.print ("*");
                anArray [i][j] = "";
            }
        }
    }
    public static void picture () {
        horizontalLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: *"make a picture"*  Do you mean make [ASCII art](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII_art) (text characters arranged to look like an image) or an actual [`Image`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html) or [`BufferedImage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html)?  *"If you could help that would be great."* It would also be great if you could ask a (specific) question.  What is your question?

Comment: I need to arrange the asterisks to look like an image. I don't know how to place an asterisk at a specific coordinate (Ex. anArray [0][2]). What I also forgot to mention in the description was I also need blank spaces in between the asterisks. I hope you understand what I am saying.

Comment: What do you want to draw in ASCII art?  Where is the data for that coming from (e.g. hard-coded by you, generated from an existing image, supplied by the user in arguments..)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You solely have to assign the desired symbol to the array positions that you want (*e.g.,*  `anArray [i][j] = "*";`). Fill up the renaming array positions with spaces (*e.g.,* `anArray [i][j] = " ";`), or another symbol for that matter. Finally, after the `anArray` is completely populated, print its content out.
For example:

```
String [][] anArray = new String [N][M];
 
for ( i = 0; i < N; i ++)
  for ( j = 0; j < M; j ++)
  {
    if(i == 0 || i == N-1 || j == 0 || j == M-1) anArray[i][j] = "*"; // Put * on the frame
    else anArray[i][j] = " "; // Put spaces inside
                    
   }

 for ( i = 0; i < N; i ++)  //Print the picture
   for ( j = 0; j < M; j ++)
   {
       printf("%s",anArray[i][j]);
       if(j == M-1) printf("\n");
   }
```